# How to disable debug option VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

When I run compile in Release mode I get the following notification:

> Use a debug build configuration or disable the debug option 'Enable
>   Just My Code'

Then:

> Check the 'Symbols' settings under debugging options.

How to turn off debug options?

Comment: Also I see that there is not compied project in directory `/bin/Release`

Comment: have you checked this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to tools select javascript -> code validation -> switch the enable JavaScript errors on or off as you like .

[image]